# Adding Link to Cell in Jquery Easy UI

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, jquery-easyui

I want to add print button in the following datagrid table using formatter.

Datagrid:

```
 <thead>
    <tr>
    <th field="id" align="center" sortable="true" >ID</th>
    <th field="name"  sortable="true">Name</th>
    <th field="department" align="center" sortable="true">Department</th>
    <th field="phone" align="center" sortable="true">Phone No</th>
    <th data-options="field:'id', formatter:quickPrint">Print</th>
 </thead>
```

The formatter function:

```
  function quickPrint(val,row){
      var url = "print.php?id=";
      return '<a href="'+url + row.id+'">Print</a>';
  }
```

Print.php

```
 <?php
   $id=htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']);
   //my other codes go here
  ?>
```

I want to send id value in `print.php` file and get the id value using `$_GET`. The problem is that only `id` values are displayed and they don't have clickable link. Any help and suggestions are greatly welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove the first id row  in your datagrid like below:

```
<thead>
<tr>    
<th field="name"  align="left">Name</th>
<th field="department" align="left" sortable="true">Department</th>
<th field="phone" align="right" sortable="true">Phone No</th>
<th field="id" align="center" formatter="quickPrint">Print</th>
</thead>
```

Your function should go like this:

```
<script>
function quickPrint(value,row){
    var url = 'print.php?id='+row.id;
    return '<a target="_blank" href="' + url + '"><button>Print</button></a>';
    }
</script>
```

Hope this may help.